# technical name of the small part from a large panel

Tags: word-request, image-identification

I am not native and are writing an essay, I am trying my best to use the appropriate word to describe the product, could I call the small red circled one **tab**? or **fragment** I are not sure the precise technical word, thank you so much for your kindness help.

[image: one panel: a square with a small square sticking out on the right top and right bottom]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. It's not clear if this is wood or made from a wood product, it looks like sheet metal in the photo. Regardless, there wouldn't be a single word in English for something like this (that's English for you!) but instead different individuals would refer to it using a word that they liked/thought was suitable. Multiple words in English have somewhat overlapping meanings, or actually mean the same thing. You could call this a **tab** and a certain proportion of people would understand, as in the sentence "a square panel with tabs at two corners".

Comment: "fragment" suggests that the item has broken or is broken off. "Tab" is much better.

Comment: This shouldn't have been migrated here.  The OP asks for the technical term.  ELL isn't set up to answer technical questions about such terminology.  The ELL answer is "a bit that sticks out" We aren't woodworkers (or sheet metal workers etc)  vote to close and reject migration.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question of technical terminology should be answered on an appropriate technical site such as [woodworking.se]

Comment: Technical domains often have very specific terminology for such things. This looks a bit like a "tenon" to me, but I know little about making joints. If you said "tab" I think many english speakers would understand.